# Getting value of clicked element in PHP

Tags: php, element, key-value

I have a page with element `<a>` acting like a `<button>`, in this form the elements works like a service plans, and i want to get a value when one of these buttons has been clicked.

**Page1.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Page 1</title>
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
</head>
    <body>

        <section>
            <a href="page2.php" value='basic' name="plan">Choose Plan1</a>
            <br><br>
            <a href="page2.php" value='intermediary' name="plan">Choose Plan2</a>
            <br><br>
            <a href="page2.php" value='premium' name="plan">Choose Plan3</a>
        </section>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Page2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'test';
echo $_POST['name'];
?>
```

I know that `$_POST['name']` doesn't works cuz don't exist a input, but i don't know how use something like this to get a value of button clicked and show this value.

The return expected for first button for example, is something like:

```
basic
```

> I need this value to put in database after.

Someone can help me to get this values?

Comment: Can you show us the form ?

Comment: @executable I use only some elements in this page, the form mentioned i use after this page, sorry for not explain good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass the value as a url parameter

```html
        <section>
            <a href="page2.php?plan=basic" >Choose Plan1</a>
            <br><br>
            <a href="page2.php?plan=intermediary">Choose Plan2</a>
            <br><br>
            <a href="page2.php?plan=premium">Choose Plan3</a>
        </section>
```

And get it from $_GET in your php code

```php
echo $_GET['plan'];
```

Comment: Worked, tks dude <3333